# Continous function approximating the precision of a number.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, soft-question

Let us say we have a number $c \in [0,1]$ in some basis: $$c = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kb^{-k}$$
For instance b=2, $a_k \in\{0,1\}$ would be binary and $b=10, a_k \in \{0, \cdots, 9\}$ would be decimal.

Is there some continous function which can calculate or estimate for a specific $c$ the smallest $k$ such that $a_l = 0, l>k$.

Maybe something with logarithms?

---

**Edit**: What if we assume the representation is finite:
$$c = \sum_{k=1}^{k_{max}} a_kb^{-k}$$

Also as other people have mentioned, what I asked for in the original question is impossible for functions only allowed to take the values of integers, so what I am looking for is a continous function *approximating* the smallest integer $k$. Let us say I would like the function value to be real and differ by maximum of say, $0.5$ from $k$ or by as little as possible "on average".

Comment: Certainly not continuous. All continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb Z$ are constant.

Comment: How would you deal with e.g. $b=10,c=\frac{1}{3}=0.333\ldots$? Or are you assuming that the representation of $c$ is finite?

Comment: What you describe is not even a well defined function, since $c=\frac13$ does not have any value of $k$ for which $a_l=0$ for $l>k$...

Comment: @5xum that actually depends what you choose for $b$, as for $b=3$ you have $$\frac{1}{3}=0.1_3.$$ Edit: thinking about your comment I see your point, hence my question if OP assumes that the given representation actually fulfills $a_l=0, l>k$ for some $k$.

Comment: @Hirshy Sure, but you are still left with $\frac14$ that has no $k$ (if $b=3$). Even worse, take $c=\sqrt2$...

Comment: @5xum technically speaking one could set for this hypothetical function $f(\sqrt{2})=\infty$, but you're right, my thoughts were heading into a different direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $l$ is defined only for $c$ rational that, expressed in lowest terms, have denominators whose prime factorization only includes prime factors of $b$. Such a function can't be continuous.